# Hide users from XP Welcome screen?

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

How can I hide certain users from the XP Welcome screen?

I Would prefer a solution not involving Windows Registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to touch the registry yourself, you can use:

- Microsoft's [TweakUI for XP](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/c/a/fca6767b-9ed9-45a6-b352-839afb2a2679/TweakUiPowertoySetup.exe)
- IntelliAdmin's [XPUserHide](http://www.intelliadmin.com/XPUserHide.exe)

Answer (score 3):

Ok.  Well... [This article](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2006/09/hide-user-accounts-from-the-windows-xp-welcome-screen/) describes how to do it if you *do* decide to brave registry diving.  But, I can understand your reluctance.  SO....  make sure you actually read through that little instructional page.  Why?  Because after they tell you how to do it yourself, they provide you with a link to a little free program they wrote that will do it all for you.  You can download it from that link, and then not have to mess around with the registry.

Seriously.  Here is a [direct link to the program](http://www.intelliadmin.com/XPUserHide.exe).  I still recommend reading through the instructions on how to do it yourself.

**EDIT**  The registry edit instructions are relatively simple, and as follows:

> The welcome screen displays all of the local users on the system, except the built-in administrator account that was created during setup. If we want to hide a specific user from the list, we need to create a special value under this registry key:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList
>
> Under this key you simply create a new DWORD value – the name matches the users name exactly, and the value is one of the following (Decimal format)
>
> 0 – Hides the user just from the welcome screen
>
> 1 – The user is shown